# how to convert to character to numeric without change the data frame elements?

Tags: r, matrix, character, numeric

There are character matrix and how i can convert to numeric in R?
   i use several codes like: as.numeric(as.character(df)); lapply(df, as.numeric); sapply(df, as.numeric); but didn't get advantage!

```
  df[1:5,1:10]
       id          G_r78   G_09   G_r805  G_800
 1    "02000H1"    NA      "1"    "2"       "1"
 2    "02000H15"   NA      "0"    "1"       "2" 
 3    "02003H10"   NA      "1"    "1"       "1"
 4    "02003KH8"   NA      "0"    "1"       "1"
```

Comment: Do you have a `matrix` ?.  If it is a data.frame, try `df[] <- lapply(df, function(x) type.convert(as.character(x), as.is = TRUE))`

Comment: typeof(df)="character" and class(df)="matrix"

Comment: In that case convert to `data.frame` first and then do as earlier commented (a matrix can have only a single class). `df <- as.data.frame(df, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)`

Comment: Change your preceding code. This data shouldn't be in a matrix but in a data.frame. So you make a mistake when creating this object.

Comment: ok. i did it. 
Now typeof(df)="dataframe".
in df[], i should specify the columns or should be empty?
 and for "x" in function(x) and as.character(x), what is x?
 thank you.

Comment: i used the df[] <- lapply(df, function(x) type.convert(as.character(x), as.is = TRUE)), BUT it didn't convert to numeric yet!

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example.